# Let $X$ and $Y$.A function $f: X \longrightarrow Y$ is continous if and only if $f^{-1}(C)$ is closed in $C$ for every closed set $C \subset Y$

Tags: general-topology, continuity

> 4.2 Let $X$ and $Y$ topological spaces.A function $f: X \longrightarrow Y$ is continous if and only if $f^{-1}(C)$ is closed in $C$ for every closed set $C \subset Y$

Answer (score 1):

> Remark:

> Theorem1.2:  Let $f: A \longrightarrow B$, $Y \subset B$ then $f^{-1}(B^{c})=(f^{-1}(B))^{c}$

> proof

Let $x\in f^{-1}(B^{c})$ then $f(x)\in B^{c}$, then $f(x)\not \in B$ and therefore $f(x)\not \in f^{-1}(B) \therefore x \in (f^{-1}(B))^{c}$.\
Conversely let $x\in (f^{-1}(B))^{c}$ by definition of pre image $f(x)\in (f^{-1}(B))$ then $f(x) \not \in B$ and $f(x)\in B^{c} \therefore x\in f^{-1}(B^{c})$.

> Proof of theorem1.2

Suppose $f: X \longrightarrow Y$ is continuous, by definition consider $W$ open in $Y$ then $f^{-1}(W)=V$ is open in $X$, consider $W/Y$ is close in $Y$ and notice that $f^{-1}(W/Y)=f^{-1}(W)/X=V/X$ (by Remark) which is closed in $X$.

Conversely suppose $C$ is arbitrary closed set in $Y$ and $f^{-1}(C)$ closed set in $X$.\

Since $C$ is closed in $Y$ then $W=C/Y$ is open in $Y$ and $f^{-1}(W)=f^{-1}(C/Y)=f^{-1}(C)/X=V$ which is open in $X$ since $f^{-1}(C)$ is closed in $X$  then their complement is open. Since $C$ was arbitrary closed in $Y$ $f$ is a continuous function.